# Can Mandrill route inbound email to webmail (like roundcube)

Tags: email, postfix, smtp

My main issue is I setup a small server, and my ISP blocks port 25.  I've setup Mandrill as a relayhost on port 587 in postfix, so that solves my sending issue.

I know Mandrill can be used to route inbound email to an application to parse the jason email, but can I route this inbound email to roundcube or similar?

Comment: You're better off with a cheap MITM VPS, to relay, I have a VPS with buyvm.net, cheapest thing will do.  Just load up postfix

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr No, it cannot.

Where do you expect that Roundcube gets its mail? Roundcube and other webmail software don't have their own mail transport system - they're merely mail **clients** just like Thunderbird, Mail.app, Outlook, etc.

So, for inbound mail, you'll either need to use something else other than Mandrill or else write an application that can parse the Mandrill json output, translate it into a standard email message, and then submit it to your SMTP server, where it will eventually land in a maildir/mbox and be available via IMAP (which then roundcube can use).

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by using a free SMTP redirect tool.  (I guess I was asking the wrong question.)

I signed up at http://ghettosmtp.com and pointed my MX records to them.  They in turn forward my incoming messages to a port of my choosing on my server.  I setup my `/etc/postfix/master.cf` to listen on said port, and now I can receive email too.